# How to get the value of the corresponding key in a (key, value) pair

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I created an RDD containing (key, value) pair by reading the file.I want to read the value of a specified key and assign it to a string.
RDD like this:

```
scala> minValue.foreach(println)
(http://subdom0003.example.com,100B)
(http://subdom0001.example.com,333B)
(http://subdom0002.example.com,8704B)
```

First,i tried to use `val a = minValue("http://subdom0003.example.com")`
it didn't work.

I tried to get the value with get, but it didn't work.

```
scala> val a = minValue.get("http://subdom0003.example.com").get
<console>:25: error: value get is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)]
       val a = minValue.get("http://subdom0003.example.com").get
```

Then I wonder if I should first map() and then get().But it is still unsuccessful

```
scala> val a = minValue.map(_.get("http://subdom0003.example.com").get)
<console>:25: error: value get is not a member of (String, String)
       val a = minValue.map(_.get("http://subdom0003.example.com").get)
```

The result I want is that if I get a key, I want to store its value in a variable.for example

```
if key = "http://subdom0003.example.com"
then val minString = 100B
```

Comment: An **RDD** is a distributed collection, you can not treat it as a normal **Map**. If you are sure it will be small enough and want to use it as a lookup table, you can `collect()` it and then turn it into a `toMap`. Or if by chance, the last thing you called on your **RDD** was `reduceByKey`, you can use `reduceByKeyLocally` instead to retrieve it as a **Map** in one step.

Comment: Thank you, my idea seems to be wrong. I have four RDDs similar to minValue, they have the same key, but the values are different, I want to put their values together.
My current thinking is that I will perform collect() on it first.
What to do after converting to array.

Comment: I think it would be better to turn the four RDDs into four DFs and then join them by key

Answer (score 1):

I think the best thing you can do is to filter your `RDD` by your key, and then get the first result with `first()` method. like this:

```
minValue.filter(_._1 == "your key").first();
```

which in your case, you should have:

```
val minString =  minValue.filter(_._1 == "http://subdom0003.example.com").first()._2
```